# how to select the parent element in my case

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I am trying to find the parent element in my directive

I have something like

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('testFuc', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    elem.closest('td').after('<div>texts here<div>');
                });
            }
        };
```

My problem is the unit test doesn't recognize `closest` method from Jquery. and had '`undefined is not a function`' error.

Instead, I have to use

```
elem.parent().parent().parent().after('<div>texts here<div>');
```

It pass the unit test but it needs 3 `parents()`. I want to know if there are better way to append the div in my case.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
ele.parents().eq(2).after('<div>texts here<div>');
```

Comment: Thanks  but it won't pass unit test. TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ele.parents()') +1 though

Comment: I use jasimine/karma.